# Python regex on phone numbers

Tags: python, regex, phone-number

I'm using the following regex to match phone numbers (still developing, so not comprehensive):

```
\(?\+[\d _\-\.\)\(\+]{8,25}[\d]{1}
```

When I test it with regex101, or regexpal.com, it matches both +442032398869 and +1 (888) 2572054.

However, when I run it with my Python script, +442032398869 does not match. Any reason for this, and how may I fix it?

Bonus question: according to my readings, I should have to do as many escapes inside the first character set. Any reason why Python's re throws me an exception if I remove the backslash in front of the . or + for instance?

EDIT:

```
def get_numbers_in_text(html_string): 
    pattern = r'\(?\+[\d _\-\.\)\(\+]{8,25}[\d]{1}
    reg = re.compile(pattern,re.IGNORECASE) 
    numbers = reg.findall(text) 
    return numbers
```

The two numbers are in two different HTML files, so I call the function twice, once for each HTML file / number.

Comment: Please provide the code, how do you run this regex in script?

Comment: It works fine for me. `+442032398869` is matched, by your given pattern.

Comment: It works well for me: http://repl.it/cHr.

Comment: You're very likely to use a wrong 're' method.

Comment: Unless you're parsing / validating phone numbers from only one country, you may want to look at [`libphonenumber`](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber), respectively its Python port [`python-phonenumbers`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers).

Comment: Just added the code. I thought of trying libphonenumber, but I wasn't sure how it would fare with the naughty numbers I'm trying to catch. But I guess it's worth a try.

Comment: `re.IGNORECASE` is not needed because you are trying to match any alpha characters.

Comment: In this situation it's not used, but I'm also interested in capturing the 'Tel', 'tel', or whatever string that might precede the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works:

```
>>> s = 'blah +442032398869 blah +1 (888) 2572054blah'
>>> re.findall(r'\(?\+[\d _\-\.\)\(\+]{8,25}[\d]{1}', s)
['+442032398869', '+1 (888) 2572054']
```

Your code indicates that you are trying to match numbers in html text.  Perhaps there is markup separating portions of the number you are trying to match.  Or perhaps the plus symbol is actually a unicode full-width plus (U+FF0B).  Or something else like it.

Comment: It does work in the interpreter, but surprisingly the number doens't end up in my db. But with a previous regex the parentheses wouldn't appear in the output string when running from the interpretor, but show up in the db when running the script. And before you ask, yes, I'm using Python 3.4 for both :)

Comment: @bsuire:  In addition to writing to database, print the values as you find them.  Then you can see if writing to database is failing.